# Copy value from observation below in SAS

Tags: sas, copy

I want to copy an observation to the lines above and below in variables with a specific characteristic (in this case the ID).If the variable is missing, no actions are required. I really have no clue how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Have:

```
ID var
1  .
1  1
1  1
1  1
1  .
1  .
1  .
2  .
2  .
2  .
2  .
2  .
3  .
3  .
3  1
3  .
4  .
4  .
4  .
4  .
```

Want:

```
ID var
1  1
1  1
1  1
1  1
1  1
1  1
1  1
2  .
2  .
2  .
2  .
2  .
3  1
3  1
3  1
3  1
4  .
4  .
4  .
4  .
```

Comment: So you expect the value of VAR to be a constant for a given value of ID?  Either missing or 1?  It that is not what you want then modify the example data to have a more complex example ID.

Answer (score 4):

Just merge the data with itself.

```
 data want;
   merge have(drop=var) have(keep=id var where=(var=1));
   by id;
 run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method: `proc timeseries` if you have SAS/ETS.

```
proc timeseries data=have out=want(drop=time);
    by id;
    var var / setmissing=maximum;
run;
```

But if it absolutely *has* to be the next value, you can run through `proc timeseries` twice: once to get the next value in-line and another to get the rest.

```
proc timeseries data=have out=have2;
    by id;
    var var / setmissing=next;
run;

proc timeseries data=have2 out=want(drop=time);
    by id;
    var var / setmissing=previous;
run;
```

Comment: Very nice :-) Love Proc Timeseries

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is SQL.

- take aggregate statistic of column and assign to new value
- Must select all variables so that a summary table is not generated

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select ID, var, max(var) as filled_var
from have
group by ID
from have;
quit;
```

Or in a data step.

- sort by ID and descending VAR, any empty values are now at the end
- Use RETAIN to hold value across rows
- Drop old variable

```
proc sort data=have;
by id descending var;
run;

data want;
set have;
retain filled_var;
if first.id then filled_var = var;
keep id filled_var;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data have;
input ID var;
datalines;
1 .
1 1
1 1
1 1
1 .
1 .
1 .
2 .
2 .
2 .
2 .
2 .
3 .
3 .
3 1
3 .
4 .
4 .
4 .
4 .
;

data want(drop = v);

   do _N_ = 1 by 1 until (last.ID);
      set have;
       by ID;
      v = max(v, var);
   end;
   
   do _N_ = 1 to _N_;
      set have;
      var = v;
       output;
   end;

run;
```